# Executing the same command on each file in a directory

Tags: python, bioinformatics

I am hoping for basic help in constructing a python script for taking each file in a directory and executing the same task on each one. I have a large number of protein files (FASTA format), and the program I'm using only allows for ~500 entries to be searched at once. So, I need to run the program for each of my 116 files separately, with various options, like "-N" and "-t 0.800". I searched for help, and I know I have to import os etc., but I've never worked with these sorts of system commands and am lost. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: If you're on a Unix-like system, you don't need Python for that. Just do `find . -type f -name "*.blah" | xargs -n 1 your_command_here`.

Comment: A cool thing with `xargs` is that you can also get it to run several commands in parallel using the `-P` option, so if you're CPU-bound and have many cores, try `-P 8` or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

```
import subprocess
for fname in list_of_files:
    r = subprocess.call(('your_command_here', '-N', '-t', '0.800', fname))
```

`subprocess.call` will run your command, wait for it to complete and return the exit code (called `r` above).

`subprocess` is quite powerful. You can read more about it [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html).

UPDATE:  I had assumed from the question that you had a list of files.  If you don't, it is easy enough to get a list.  If, for example, your files all had extension `.blah`, then use:

```
from glob import glob
list_of_files = glob('*.blah')
```

The python module `glob` accepts all the usual shell-style wildcards.

Comment: Thanks for the help. So, how am I making the list of files? Sorry for the dumb question.

Answer (score 0):

Or simply use some shell commands (below assumes bash). I usually use `echo` first to ensure everything is harmless. In the example a file name is echoed, and additionally a new file name with a different suffix (by stripping the .blah suffix and adding .result). This can be useful for grouping and associating results sensibly. You would later replace the echo command with something that runs on `$f` and stores results in `$f{%.blah}.result`.

```
for f in *.blah; do
  echo $f ${f%.blah}.result
done
```

On a single line; `for f in *.c; do echo $f ${f%.blah}.result; done`.
It is of course possible to use redirection in the above, e.g.

```
command $f > ${f%.blah}.result
```

The shell is a very natural environment to manipulate files like this. You can store the commands in a shell script as a means of documenting your workflow. Do not forget to use

```
set -e
set -o pipefail
```

so that the script exits on errors rather than blundering on. It is possible to trap such errors and run clean-up code, notifications, or anything else you may need.